# How to handle JSON encoding

Tags: json, encoding

I believe that a valid `JSON` does not contain any encoding information (as opposed to XML, for instance). Is it correct ? Does it have any "standard" encoding (e.g. `utf-8`) ? How am I supposed to handle the `JSON` encoding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [JSON RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), section 3:

> 3.  Encoding
>
> JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is
>     UTF-8.
>
> Since the first two characters of a JSON text will always be ASCII
>     characters [RFC0020], it is possible to determine whether an octet
>     stream is UTF-8, UTF-16 (BE or LE), or UTF-32 (BE or LE) by looking
>     at the pattern of nulls in the first four octets.
>
> ```
>       00 00 00 xx  UTF-32BE
>       00 xx 00 xx  UTF-16BE
>       xx 00 00 00  UTF-32LE
>       xx 00 xx 00  UTF-16LE
>       xx xx xx xx  UTF-8
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You're right. There is no encoding information. But there is also no need for it:

JSON means JavaScript Object Notation. The conclusion is, that you can directly create JavaScript objects from a JSON-text.

```
{"name":"value"}
```

This would already be a valid JSON textfile.

An example with an array:

```
{
  "employees": [
    { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
    { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
    { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
  ]
}
```

> The JSON text format is syntactically identical to the code for creating JavaScript objects.
>
> Because of this similarity, instead of using a parser, a JavaScript program can use the built-in eval() function and execute JSON data to produce native JavaScript objects.

See also here: http://www.w3schools.com/json/